# alignment within algorithm environment

Tags: horizontal-alignment, algorithms, pseudocode

I would like to align some statements so that it's more pleasing to the eye. I have the following code, where the first version the two statements are not aligned. I use `\phantom` to force alignment but this introduces necessary space. It would be nice to place some text within a specified *maximum* width, but I don't know if this is possible with LaTeX. This is the MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[noend]{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algorithmicx}

\newcommand*\Let[2]{\State #1 $\gets$ #2}


\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}[!h]
  \caption{Integration }
\begin{minipage}{\textwidth} 
\begin{algorithmic}
 \Let{$\mathbf k$} {$ \mathbf k + j  \mathbf w \left[ i \right] \mathbf B $}
 \Let{$\mathbf r $} {$ \mathbf r - j   \mathbf w \left[ i \right]  \mathbf B$}
\end{algorithmic}
\end{minipage}
\end{algorithm}

\begin{algorithm}[!h]
  \caption{Integration }
\begin{minipage}{\textwidth} 
\begin{algorithmic}
 \Let{$\phantom{\mathbf{r}}\mathbf k$} {$ \phantom{\mathbf{r}} \mathbf k \phantom{-}+ j  \mathbf w \left[ i \right] \mathbf B $}
 \Let{$\phantom{\mathbf{k}}\mathbf r $} {$ \phantom{\mathbf{k}} \mathbf r \phantom{+}- j   \mathbf w \left[ i \right]  \mathbf B$}
\end{algorithmic}
\end{minipage}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

which produces[image]